# How do you add a list to jump to a line on my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Have a python code to fix phones and i was wondering what was the best way to jump to a particular question when i type in for example 'Broken Screen'

im really stuck and need this done i appreciate immensely all answers

```
def menu():
   print("Welcome to Sams Phone Troubleshooting program")
   print("Please Enter your name")
   name=input()
   print("Thanks for using Kierans Phone Troubleshooting program "+name)
   print("Would you like to start this program? Please enter either y for yes or n for no")  
   select=input()
   if select=="y":
      troubleshooter()
   elif select=="n":
      quit
   else:
      print("Invalid please enter again")
      menu()
def troubleshooter():
   print("Does Your Phone Turn On")
   answer=input()
   if answer=="y":
      print("Does it freeze?")
   else:
      print("Have you plugged in a charger?")
   answer=input()

   if answer=="y":
      print("Charge it with a diffrent charger in a diffrent phone socket")
   else:
      print("Plug it in and leave it for 20 mins, has it come on?")
   answer=input()

   if answer=="y":
      print("Is there any more problems?")
   else:
      print("Is the screen cracked?")
   answer=input()

   if answer=="y":
      print("Restart this program")
   else:
      print("Thank you for using my troubleshooting program!")
   answer=input()

   if answer=="y":
      print("Replace screen in a shop")
   else:
      print("Take it to a specialist")
   answer=input()

   if answer=="y":
      print("Did you drop your device in water?")
   else:
      print("Make sure the sim card is inserted properly and do a hard reset on the device")
   answer=input()

   if answer=="y":
      print("Do not charge it and take it to the nearest specialist")
   else:
      print("Try a hard reset when the battery has charge")
   answer=input()



menu()
```

Comment: What would i need to add to the code ? and btw thank you very much

Comment: Split up the logic into separate questions which you can call individually.

Comment: could you please do it i would be very grateful

Comment: No, please try it yourself. If you end up having problems, we can help, but you should try solving it yourself first.

Comment: Did my answer help you at all, or were you wanting something different?

Comment: i was wanting more of a keyword search to a certain question please thank you very much you have really helped me im stressing so much and youre helping me, thank you

Comment: @KieranMcCarthy Did you find any of the answers to this particular question helpful in solving your problem?

Comment: yes thank you very much I have made a new question if you can answer me as you are very talented thank you :))))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code should provide a framework on which to build and extend the program in your question. Most of the code should be fine as it currently written, but you can expand its functionality if needed. To continue building on what questions can be asked and what answers are given, consider adding more sections to the database at the top of the file. The cases are can be easily augmented.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

"""Cell Phone Self-Diagnoses Program

The following program is designed to help users to fix problems that they may
encounter while trying to use their cells phones. It asks questions and tries
to narrow down what the possible cause of the problem might be. After finding
the cause of the problem, a recommended action is provided as an attempt that
could possibly fix the user's device."""

# This is a database of questions used to diagnose cell phones.
ROOT = 0
DATABASE = {
            # The format of the database may take either of two forms:
            # LABEL: (QUESTION, GOTO IF YES, GOTO IF NO)
            # LABEL: ANSWER
            ROOT: ('Does your phone turn on? ', 1, 2),
            1: ('Does it freeze? ', 11, 12),
            2: ('Have you plugged in a charger? ', 21, 22),
            11: ('Did you drop your device in water? ', 111, 112),
            111: 'Do not charge it and take it to the nearest specialist.',
            112: 'Try a hard reset when the battery has charge.',
            12: 'I cannot help you with your phone.',
            21: 'Charge it with a different charger in a different phone '
                'socket.',
            22: ('Plug it in and leave it for 20 minutes. Has it come on? ',
                 221, 222),
            221: ('Are there any more problems? ', 222, 2212),
            222: ('Is the screen cracked? ', 2221, 2222),
            2212: 'Thank you for using my troubleshooting program!',
            2221: 'Replace in a shop.',
            2222: 'Take it to a specialist.'
            }

# These are possible answers accepted for yes/no style questions.
POSITIVE = tuple(map(str.casefold, ('yes', 'true', '1')))
NEGATIVE = tuple(map(str.casefold, ('no', 'false', '0')))


def main():
    """Help diagnose the problems with the user's cell phone."""
    verify(DATABASE, ROOT)
    welcome()
    ask_questions(DATABASE, ROOT)


def verify(database, root):
    """Check that the database has been formatted correctly."""
    db, nodes, visited = database.copy(), [root], set()
    while nodes:
        key = nodes.pop()
        if key in db:
            node = db.pop(key)
            visited.add(key)
            if isinstance(node, tuple):
                if len(node) != 3:
                    raise ValueError('tuple nodes must have three values')
                query, positive, negative = node
                if not isinstance(query, str):
                    raise TypeError('queries must be of type str')
                if len(query) < 3:
                    raise ValueError('queries must have 3 or more characters')
                if not query[0].isupper():
                    raise ValueError('queries must start with capital letters')
                if query[-2:] != '? ':
                    raise ValueError('queries must end with the "? " suffix')
                if not isinstance(positive, int):
                    raise TypeError('positive node names must be of type int')
                if not isinstance(negative, int):
                    raise TypeError('negative node names must be of type int')
                nodes.extend((positive, negative))
            elif isinstance(node, str):
                if len(node) < 2:
                    raise ValueError('string nodes must have 2 or more values')
                if not node[0].isupper():
                    raise ValueError('string nodes must begin with capital')
                if node[-1] not in {'.', '!'}:
                    raise ValueError('string nodes must end with "." or "!"')
            else:
                raise TypeError('nodes must either be of type tuple or str')
        elif key not in visited:
            raise ValueError('node {!r} does not exist'.format(key))
    if db:
        raise ValueError('the following nodes are not reachable: ' +
                         ', '.join(map(repr, db)))


def welcome():
    """Greet the user of the application using the provided name."""
    print("Welcome to Sam's Phone Troubleshooting program!")
    name = input('What is your name? ')
    print('Thank you for using this program, {!s}.'.format(name))


def ask_questions(database, node):
    """Work through the database by asking questions and processing answers."""
    while True:
        item = database[node]
        if isinstance(item, str):
            print(item)
            break
        else:
            query, positive, negative = item
            node = positive if get_response(query) else negative


def get_response(query):
    """Ask the user yes/no style questions and return the results."""
    while True:
        answer = input(query).casefold()
        if answer:
            if any(option.startswith(answer) for option in POSITIVE):
                return True
            if any(option.startswith(answer) for option in NEGATIVE):
                return False
        print('Please provide a positive or negative answer.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If there is something wrong with this answer, please provide either an edit to fix the problem or a comment making a recommendation to improve it.

Comment: Thank you very much sir youre very talented :)

Comment: @KieranMcCarthy Please consider reading [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If the code shown above suits your needs, you might want to accept the answer.

Comment: im sorry im new and im stressing about this code im sorry but its not quite what im looking for thank you very much tho i was looking for more of a code with keywords which then jumps to a certain question my skype is kkid19 and would be over the moon if you could help me as i would give you everything i can on this website

Comment: @KieranMcCarthy That is exactly what the `DATABASE` at the top of the program does. Let us take the line `1: ('Does it freeze? ', 11, 12),` as an example. It means that the label is "1" for the following question. The question is `Does it freeze?`. If the answer is positive, goto label "11;" but if the answer is negative, goto label "12" instead. We can look at another example: `2221: 'Replace in a shop.',` This line means that the label is 2221. This is not a question but an answer that terminates the program. The answer is `Replace in a shop.` You can extend the database as much as you want.

Comment: I would Like it so when you put a keyword it jumps to a quetion for example if i put "Screen Not coming on" it would pick out screen or not then jump to a set of questions again thank you please let me know if you cant do it as it is very hard

Comment: so it would just ask me "what is your problem" then i would but "screen froze" and it would jump to a question on yes my screen is broke thank you very much i understand if you cant do it as it is hard but it would litreally mean the world if you could :)

Comment: @KieranMcCarthy What you are asking for does not sound too difficult; but a small sample database of questions, answers, and goto instructions would be nice to start out with. Could you perhaps provide some pseudocode for what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: im sorry i i have a basic level of python if you could start it i could have a look at it and finish the final touches once again thank you its very hard

Comment: @KieranMcCarthy You came with a question, and an answer was given that appears to solve the original question. You wanted to be able to ask questions and jump to other questions based on a given response. The answer above allows you to easily do this and extend the number of questions that can be asked along with the answers that can be given. Now you are asking something completely different. You want a program that allows the user to state a problem or ask a question. You need to open a new question on this web site if you want it answered because you have just come up with a different one.

Comment: im sorry thats what i meant in the first place im really stressed sorry

Comment: i understand if i frustrated you but thats what i meant in the first place im very sorry id appriciate it if you could have one more look at it :_(

Comment: @KieranMcCarthy If you want to ask a second question, you need to open a new one of this web site. When you do, make sure you follow the guidelines in [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before submitting. You will also want to make sure your program provides [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. At the very least, you should list out some of your questions, possible answers to your questions, and where to go based on the user's input.

Comment: @KieranMcCarthy If you found an answer helpful in solving your problem, you may want mark it as accepted (as you have done in another question of yours).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best attempt I had at replicating your code. 
I made a couple of the problems def() so that you can call each one separately.
I hope this is what you wanted!

```
def menu():
  print("Welcome to Sams Phone Troubleshooting program")
  print("Please Enter your name")
  name=input()
  print("Thanks for using Kierans Phone Troubleshooting program "+name +"\n")

def start():
  select = " "
  print("Would you like to start this program? Please enter either y for yes or n for no")
  select=input()
  if select=="y":
    troubleshooter()
  elif select=="n":
    quit
  else:
    print("Invalid please enter again")

def troubleshooter():
  print("""Please choose the problem you are having with your phone (input 1-4):
1) My phone doesn't turn on
2) My phone is freezing
3) The screen is cracked
4) I dropped my phone in water\n""")
  problemselect = int(input())
  if problemselect ==1:
    not_on()
  elif problemselect ==2:
    freezing()
  elif problemselect ==3:
    cracked()
  elif problemselect ==4:
    water()
  start()

def not_on():
  print("Have you plugged in the charger?")
  answer = input()
  if answer =="y":
    print("Charge it with a diffrent charger in a diffrent phone socket. Does it work?")
  else:
    print("Plug it in and leave it for 20 mins, has it come on?")
  answer = input()
  if answer=="y":
    print("Are there any more problems?")
  else:
    print("Restart the troubleshooter or take phone to a specialist\n")
  answer=input()
  if answer =="y":
    print("Restart this program")
  else:
    print("Thank you for using my troubleshooting program!\n")

def freezing():
  print("Charge it with a diffrent charger in a diffrent phone socket")
  answer = input("Are there any more problems?")
  if answer=="y":
    print("Restart the troubleshooter or take phone to a specialist\n")
  else:
    print("Restart this program\n")

def cracked():
  answer =input("Is your device responsive to touch?")
  if answer=="y":
    answer2 = input("Are there any more problems?")
  else:
    print("Take your phone to get the screen replaced")
  if answer2=="y":
    print("Restart the program or take phone to a specialist\n")
  else:
    print("Thank you for using my troubleshooting program!\n")

def water():
  print("Do not charge it and take it to the nearest specialist\n")

menu()
while True:
  start()
  troubleshooter()
```

Hope this helps somewhat and if there are minor problems with the code then just message me! (I'm relatively new to this site!)

Comment: Thank you so much i appriciate your help so much youre a very kind hearted person, however i was asking more of me typing in a keyword like "Screen froze" rather than numbers , again thank you so much youve healped me so much :)))

Comment: my skype is kkid19 if you would like to help me i would be overly thankful

Comment: @KieranMcCarthy not sure if you've fixed your problem but just changing the numbers to the keywords should be what you want! Change `problemselect == 1` to `problemselect == "Broken Screen"` etc and see if that works :) might need a bit of tweaking, but best of luck to you!!