# I'm trying to solve this and the ("display" or "screen") works fine but i can't get the other part to work

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve this and the ("display" or "screen") works fine but i can't get the other part to work as it simply stops the code. Just in case the link doesn't work here it is:

```
if ("display" or "screen") and ("broken" or "blank" or 'black') in problem: 
    print('So your screen is broken? interesting.')
```

Comment: Actually, if "works fine" means "does what you think," no part of that works fine.

Comment: it does as when I type in " my display is broken" It works (the print bit is indented)

Comment: Try something that doesn't include "display" or "broken" and you will see that the program can't tell.

Comment: it works with screen, it's the other bit (blank or black) that i'm trying to figure out what to replace with

Comment: And I'm telling you that no, it does not work with "screen." Conduct more tests and you will see that the program always behaves the same way, because `if ("display" or "screen"):` always evaluates to true.

Comment: Also, have you done any research on Google? SO is full of questions about phone repair programs ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516994/how-do-i-split-the-solutions-for-my-code), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440277/how-can-i-put-keywords-into-my-code/35463021), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413563/how-do-you-add-a-list-to-jump-to-a-line-on-my-code), etc.).

Comment: K, i'll take a look there then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `("display" or "screen")` returns `"display"` and `("broken" or "blank" or 'black')` returns `"broken"`, so you are not searching for what you want to be searching.

Try this:

```
if "display" in problem or "screen" in problem:
    if "broken" in problem or "black" in problem or "blank" in problem:
         print('So your screen is broken? interesting.')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if any number of sub-strings may be contained in a string, then you might want to take the following approach as a guide to a possible solution to solving the problem you are working on:

```
def main():
    problem = input('What is your problem? ')
    if in_(problem, 'display', 'screen') and \
            in_(problem, 'broken', 'blank', 'black'):
        print('So your screen is broken? Interesting.')


def in_(string, *substrings):
    return any(substring in string for substring in substrings)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```